# Good Practice for Get RestFul WebService?

Tags: java, rest, web-services, spring-boot

I would like to understand one thing regarding GET restful webservice . I have encounter a scenario where i need to pass many request params in GET Operation and need to get the List of objects on the based of the request params. Is it a good practice to send the string of json as a single request param to web service and parse the json and do the needful.

NOTE: the params are not sensitive information.

Alternate Way i am thinking is to make the API as Post and pass the json as request body and retrieve the list of object (as this is against standard of web service).

Comment: No, that is not a good practice. In RESTful web-apps, `GET` requests are for specific resources. A request with a lot of parameters is a *query* and should use `POST`.

Comment: @Andreas thanks for quick response , but POST is used to do any create or update operation , but in my case i just need to retrieve the list ,Is it good i go with POST ??

Comment: Because of URL length constraints on web servers, it is valid to use POST as a *query*. One definition of `POST` that I've [seen](https://spring.io/understanding/REST#user-content-post) is: *Request that the resource at the URI **do something** with the provided entity.* "Do something" doesn't mandate updating the system, it can also be "go find this for me".